# Error in reading multple text files from directory in R

Tags: r, text-processing, data-extraction

I would like to read multiple text files from my directory   the files are arranged in following format

```
 regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt
 regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt
 ........
 regional_vol_GM_atlas152.txt
```

Data from the files looks in following format

```
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
3631 3631
```

following is the script that i have written

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

array <- c()  
for (file in dir(/media/dev/Daten/Task1/subject1/t1)) # path to the directory where .txt files are located
  {  

  row4 <- read.table(file=list.files(pattern ="regional_vol*.txt"),
                     header = FALSE,
                     row.names = NULL,
                     skip = 3,  # Skip the 1st 3 rows
                     nrows = 1,  # Read only the next row after skipping the 1st 3 rows
                     sep = "\t")  # change the separator if it is not "\t"  
  array <- cbind(array, row4)
}
```

I am incurring following error

```
 Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

kindly suggest me where i was wrong in the script

Comment: `myfiles <- lapply(list.files(...), read.table(...) )` is a better pattern

Comment: OP: The code is effectively passing multiple files `(list.files())` to `read.table`

Comment: @R.S. the values of stored in row4, there are 900 files, so i expect 900 values, but i only see 1 value

Comment: @arvi1000 , My intention is to extract the data in the fourth row from the text files, with the code above i can only extract first 3 rows

Comment: I think it means that the top row is becoming the header.

Comment: @R.S.  I would like to skip first three rows in each file and extract fourth row from each file and there are 900 text files in my directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me. Make changes as per code comments in case files have headers :
 [Answer Edited to reflect new information posted by OP]

```r
# rm(list=ls()) #clean memory if you can afford to

mydir<- "~/Desktop/a" #change as per your path
# read full paths
myfiles<- list.files(mydir,pattern = "regional_vol*",full.names=T)
myfiles #check that files listed correctly

# initialise the dataframe from first file 
# change header =T/F depending on presence of header
# make sure sep is correct      

df<- read.csv( myfiles[1], header = F, skip = 0, nrows = 4, sep="" )[-c(1:3),]
#check that first line was read correctly
df
#read all the other files and update dataframe
#we read 4 lines to read the header correctly, then remove 3
ans<- lapply(myfiles[-1], function(x){  read.csv( x, header = F, skip = 0, nrows = 4, sep="")[-c(1:3),]       })
ans


#update dataframe
lapply(ans, function(x){df<<-rbind(df,x)}  )

#this should be the required dataframe
df
```

Also, if you are on Linux, a much simple method would be to simply make the OS do it for you

```
awk 'FNR == 4' regional_vol*.txt
```

Comment: I would like to extract the fourth row of each text file into an array but when i see the data frame ans, i see nothing being imported

Comment: The values inside myfiles is empty

Comment: Now i am getting right answer , how can i store the values in an array, i upvoted your reply

Comment: I cannot see any values in dataframe but i see list of values in ans

Comment: Now you have a data.frame so you can do anything you wish. Try `array(df)`

Comment: The out put of array(df) is integer(0)

Comment: Output of dataframe  View(df)
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: That's because of empty df. can you post some data from one of those files? and the `<<- ` operator in the second  `lapply ` line  is there? With the two `<<` ?

Comment: I have updated the question and posted the data from the files

Comment: oh.. the files don;t have a header. Give me 10-20 mins. I'll get back to it and post the new answer

Comment: just change `header=T` to `header=F` in both lines. That does the trick for me

Comment: I did it but i do not get array of values i only get this output :> df
   [,1]
df    3

Comment: Only other thing I could think of was the separator `sep` . I've edited the answer. For me it works perfectly with the file format you'd posted

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

```
# set the working directory (where files are saved)
setwd("C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/")

file_names = list.files(getwd())
file_names = file_names[grepl(".TXT",file_names)]

# print file_names vector
file_names

# read the WY.TXT file, just for testing
# file = read.csv("C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)

# see the data structure
str(file)

# run read.csv on all values of file_names
files = lapply(file_names, read.csv, header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)
files = do.call(rbind,files)

# set column names
names(files) = c("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5")
str(files)


write.table(files, "C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/mydata.txt", sep="\t")
write.csv(files,"C:/Users/your_path_here/Desktop/mydata.csv")
```